# Raw partition access in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, disk-partitioning

Accessing a raw disk partition in Windows Vista requires kernel mode control, as opposed to for instance WinXP where you can access it from user mode.

However, I've heard that when it comes to USB flash memory, a partition can still be accessed from user mode even on Windows Vista.

Is this true?

Regards

/Robert

Comment: I have set a bounty on a similar question [CreateFile: direct write operation to raw disk “Access is denied” - Vista, Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8694713/341970). Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on Vista, you may need admin rights, but no special kernel mode driver is needed.

This question shows how to do it [How do I read a disk directly with .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190/how-do-i-read-a-disk-directly-with-net)  I was reading the data off the USB stick directly as the file system on the stick was corrupted.

Comment: I have a similar question, could you help me? [CreateFile: “Access is denied” even with Administrator privileges - Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8694713/341970)

Comment: @Ali Sorry I haven't tried writing directly.