# Microsoft Azure: Get Local Disk Address of Blob File

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

My code below uploads an Excel file from a user's form submission. However, I'd like to work with the Excel file using EPplus to write it to the database. For that, I need the file's address on the disk, rather than the web address. How can I get that?

Relevant code:

```
{
    public class ExcelService
    {
        public async Task<string> UploadExcelAsync(HttpPostedFileBase upload)
        {
            string excelFullPath = null;
            if (upload == null || upload.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            try
            {
                CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = ConnectionString.GetConnectionString();
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("excel");

                if (await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
                {
                    await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(
                        new BlobContainerPermissions
                        {
                            PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                        }
                        );
                }
                string excelName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "-" + Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);

                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(excelName);
                cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = upload.ContentType;
                await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(upload.InputStream);

                excelFullPath = cloudBlockBlob.Uri.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return excelFullPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800216/how-to-get-file-physical-location-on-hard-drive

Comment: I don't believe this is relevant to my request.

Comment: Are you looking for it's memory address or where it physically is on disk?

Comment: I'm not really sure of the distinction. I need the address in the form "/SomeFolder/MyFile.xlsx" and instead all that I'm able to get it a full web URL to the file.

Comment: If you're uploading to a web address, and you don't own the server you're uploading to or have direct access to IIS or some other webserver, I don't see how you would expect to get where it actually lives on the endpoint you're uploading to

Comment: This surprises me. I'm just trying to read the file name/path into my code here: var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Excel"), fileName); -- This is the code I was using previously when developing locally, but upon migrating to Azure I had to switch to Blob storage method instead of folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Azure Storage Blobs is a cloud service that only exposes web access to the stored blobs, so there is no physical location on a disk you can access. So unless you download the file, edit it and upload it again there is not way to edit it directly.

An alternative could be to use [Azure Storage Files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/). Still an Azure Cloud based service for storage but it allows you to map folders to your machine so you can access it like any network share. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction). This, of course, only works if you are able to create a file share on the web server.

Unfortunately you cannot access Azure Storage Files shares using Azure Web Apps ([source](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6084609-allow-map-azure-file-share-microsoft-azure-file-s#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)) so if that it how your web app is hosted than you are out of luck for that.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I'll consider some alternatives.