# C# read / write to physical disk

Tags: c#, io, hard-drive

Just wondering if there is any APIs that will let a .NET program write to a partition without entering kernel mode. I am developing an OS and just want to write a quick program on windows so I can add files to a partition shared with VMware. If I had the time I would write actual drivers for it, but I just want something to make something quick. I remember seeing a .NET program for modding Xbox games that could read and write directly to FatX Formatted USB flashdrives.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28314/Reading-and-Writing-to-Raw-Disk-Sectors , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399485/direct-disk-access-in-windows-c (only vague answer given) , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190/how-do-i-read-a-disk-directly-with-net (only some systems) and similar

Comment: You can't do any sort of disk access without entering kernel mode. Maybe you mean without writing code that executes in kernel mode?

Comment: Lol thats what I ment.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like "\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1" as path.

Comment: Windows uses device files?

Comment: I'm still pretty sure it's device level, though I really don't want to install windows just to check it. Give it a try, eh?

Comment: I found a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190/how-do-i-read-a-disk-directly-with-net) with a wrapper that will work with that, thanks