# System.OutOfMemoryException when calling Path.GetFullPath()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, path, out-of-memory

My code here `var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(input);` throws OutOfMemoryException Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program when I pass this value "\\." as argument. Any explanation as to why `Path.GetFullPath("\\.")` crashes?

XAML:

```
<TextBox><TextBox.Text><Binding Path="FolderPath" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True"/></TextBox.Text></TextBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
// Implementation of IDataErrorInfo
public string this[string columnName]
{
   get
   {
      if (columnName != null)
      {
         if (columnName.Equals(nameof(FolderPath)))
         {
            if(!Validator.IsValidPath(FolderPath)
                 return "Invalid Folder";
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Validator Class:

```
private static bool IsValidPath(string input)
{
   bool isValid = false;
   try
   {
      var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(input);
      return input.Equals(fullPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      isValid = false;
   }
   return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Does this happen when you are debugging? What is the path to the executable that is calling that code?

Comment: Sounds like leaking file handles. Are you calling that function in a loop, in rapid succession? If you are try a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)` ..

Comment: Do you build it to x86 or x64 CPU target?

Comment: @Logarr no, it also happens in the installed applcation

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew x86

Comment: Could you try changing it to x64 to see if it help

Comment: @JeremyThompson this method is called when text is changed in textbox

Comment: @markuy please post a complete minimal example of the code that causes this. Something isn't making sense here. Jeremy is likely right, and I think your code is doing something else that you don't notice or understand.

Comment: @Logarr Thanks. I updated the post with the sample implementation

Comment: @RawitasKrungkaew it does not occur in x64. the crash happens when I set the Build Platform target as Any CPU and check the Prefer 32-bit tickbox

Answer (score 0):

> Any explanation as to why Path.GetFullPath("\.") crashes?

Per MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx

**Remarks**
The .NET Framework does not support direct access to physical disks through paths that are device names, such as "\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 ".

You'll either need to use pinvoke, [Direct disk access in windows (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399485/direct-disk-access-in-windows-c) or perhaps this library might help
[CCS LABS C#: Low Level Disk Access](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CCS-LABS-C-Low-Level-Disk-91676ca9).

Comment: thanks Jeremy. we've narrowed down the cause and as what Rawitas mentioned, it could be related to the build platform. My code above works if target platform is x64. But when I set it to x32 or Any CPU with preferred 32-bit, it gives the memory exception

Comment: @markuy That's what is known as an X Y problem. You shouldn't be running out of memory for such a simple process. The memory usage is a symptom of a bigger problem.