# How to read and write data directly from disk partition on Windows with random access?

Tags: windows, volume, random-access

I can open a disk, and do some reads and writes (described here: [How do I read a disk directly with .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190/how-do-i-read-a-disk-directly-with-net)), but I don't know how to seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API function you are looking for is [`SetFilePointerEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542.aspx).