# How to I access a drive at the block/sector level using C#?

Tags: c#, filesystems, block, sector

I am working on an embedded project where data is stored on an SD card using no filesystem (I write data to specific blocks).  My embedded device provides a mass-storage interface to the device, but there is no formatted filesystem on the device.

I was wondering how to access the device and read a specified sector at a time?  I found a reference to pinvoke, but I wasn't able to figure out much by looking at pinvoke's website.

Any suggestions would be appreciated; thanks!

Comment: The important bit is to find the API for said "embedded device" (this can then be p/invoked) - this is tagged C# - but what OS/run-time?

Comment: Here is a blog post detailing what you are looking for.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28314/Reading-and-Writing-to-Raw-Disk-Sectors

Comment: Assume it's just a mass storage device.  I figured out the method was through P/Invoke's kernel32 ReadFile/WriteFile.  Luckily, the drive shows up not doesn't try to get me to format it which is perfect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190/how-do-i-read-a-disk-directly-with-net/38275#38275 got me pointed in the right direction.