# How do I write to a disk directly with .Net?

Tags: .net, winapi, disk

I have found a way to read from a drive, using the method posted by Darryl Braaten
[How do I read a disk directly with .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190/how-do-i-read-a-disk-directly-with-net/38275#38275)

I am now trying to find a way to write on a drive, and in his method the write method is not implemented. Anyone could suggest a way of doing it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Importing and using `WriteFile()` function (pretty symmetric to `ReadFile()` as used there). Don't refrain to come back if you have any issue with your code doing that...

Comment: I get a Stream was not writable ,even thought i set the Handler to GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, and Filestream to FileAccess.ReadWrite. Any idea why i am gettings that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `WriteFile` P/Invoke function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool WriteFile(
    IntPtr hFile, 
    byte[] lpBuffer, 
    uint nNumberOfBytesToWrite, 
    out uint lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
    IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

Replace the `ReadFile` calls by `WriteFile`, that's pretty easy. Just keep in mind:

- the handle you got using `CreateFile` has a `write` access
- you have to write bytes per chunk; chunk size must be a multiple of the sector size. I.e. if you want to write only 1 byte, you'll have to read a whole sector, modify the byte in memory, and write back the whole sector

Comment: I have setted the Handle to GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, and Filestream FileAccess.ReadWrite, but i get a "Stream was not writable." Error.